# How to implement read and write on a file from QAbstractTableModel to

Tags: c++, qt, qabstracttablemodel

I am using [Qt Xlsx](http://qtxlsx.debao.me/) to edit and write my xlsx file.
I want to make a program that can read and write on *.xlsx file via `QAbstractTableModel`.

But i got confuse **how to implement read and write that file via QAbstractTableModel**.
How can i do this ?

Comment: Have you seen its [github examples](https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtXlsxWriter/tree/master/examples/xlsx)? There is a read function that seems to read the cells ([here](https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtXlsxWriter/blob/master/examples/xlsx/extractdata/main.cpp))

Comment: You probably want to learn more about the [Qt Model/View programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) and apply these generic information to your particular case